# Gazebo Node::Advertise(): Error advertising a topic. Did you forget to start the discovery service?

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

When I insert a box in ModelEditor, and change some pose parameter in link tab, but the box is not changed by the parameters. Then I checked the teminator and it printed error

```
Node::Advertise(): Error advertising a topic. Did you forget to start the discovery service?
Node::Advertise(): Error advertising a topic. Did you forget to start the discovery service?
Node::Advertise(): Error advertising a topic. Did you forget to start the discovery service?
Node::Advertise(): Error advertising a topic. Did you forget to start the discovery service?
```

What should I do to run or build model in gazebo successfully?

Comment: Hi, did you managed to find a fix?